# Read, update and save cached value atomically

Tags: multithreading, caching, hbase, streaming, spark-streaming

I have a multiple streams (N) which should update the same cache. So, assume, that there is at least N threads. Each thread may process values with similar keys. The problem is that if i do update as following:

```
1. Read old value from cache (multiple threads get the same old value)
2. Merge new value with old value (each thread update old value)
3. Save updated value back to the cache (only the last update was saved, another one is lost)
```

i can lost some updates if multiple threads will simultaneously try to update the same record. At first glance, there is a solution to make all updates atomic: for example, use `Increment` mutation in hbase or `add` in aerospike (currently, i'm considering these caches for my case). If value consists only of numeric primitive types, then it is ok, because both cache implementations support atomic inc/dec.

```
1. Inc/dec each value (cache will resolve sequence of this ops by it's self)
```

But what if value consists not only of primitives? Then i have to read value and update it in my code. In this case i still can lose some updates.

As i wrote, currently i'm considering hbase and aerospike, but both not fully fit for my case. In hbase, as i know, there is no way to lock row from client side (> ~0.98), so i have to use `checkAndPut` operation for each complex type. In aerospike i can achieve something like row-based lock using lua udfs, but i want to avoid them. Redis allow to `watch` record and if there is was update from another thread the transaction will fail and i can catch this error and try again.

So, my question is how to achieve something like row-based lock for such updates and is row-based lock will be a correct way? Maybe there is another approach?

---

```scala
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("sample")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Duration(500))

    val source = Source()
    val stream = source.stream(ssc)

    stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
        rdd.foreachPartition(partition => {
          if (partition.nonEmpty) {
            val cache = Cache()

            partition.foreach(entity=> {
// in this block if 2 distributed workers (in case of apache spark, for example) 
//will process entities with the same keys i can lose one of this update
// worker1 and worker2 will get the same value
               val value = cache.get(entity.key)
// both workers will update this value but may get different results
               val updatedValue = ??? // some non-trivial update depends on entity
// for example, worker1 put new value, then worker2 put new value. In this case only updates from worker2 are visible and updates from worker1 are lost
               cache.put(entity.key, updatedValue)
            })
          }
        })
      }
    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
```

So, in case if i use kafka as source i can workaround this if messages are partitioned by keys. In this case i can rely on the fact that only 1 worker will process particular record at any point of time. But how to handle the same situation when messages partitioned randomly (key is inside message body)?

Comment: It's not clear what you are talking about when you say "update the same record," and "lose some updates."  A concrete example (i.e., some _source code_) would be very helpful here.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, probably my question is more theoretical, but i added some almost real example, which i think will be helpful to understand what i mean